# no quiero que funcione el modo oscuro en mi aplicación

Tags: java, android, webview

bunas soy nuevo en esto y tengo un aplicación simple de Webview y veo que se afecta mucho cuando funciona el modo oscuro en los celulares, quiero saber como quitar esa opción para que no se vea afectado por el modo oscuro

Comment: No das suficiente información

Comment: Muestranos el codigo para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar añadiendo esto en el `onCreate()`:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudo mucho !!! genioo!!

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para que se cierre :) y de nada

Answer (score 0):

En el onCreate de tus activities tienes que indicar lo siguiente

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

si tienes un BaseActivity desde el que heredas el resto de actividades, lo pones ahi y asi ya lo tienes en todos.

Comment: muchas gracias !!!! fue de mucha ayuda!!!